# How to add the column for pie chart using database query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I've queried my database for creating a dataset for a Google Pie Chart but I'm unable to create the column label which should be the month name.

```
JAVASCRIPT
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "getData.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
}).responseText;
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width:400, height:240});
  }

PHP:        
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ldpage` WHERE YEAR(`frm_date`) = 2015 GROUP
 BY month(`frm_date`)";        
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection)){
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
print json_encode($sql);
```

The error shows "Table has no columns."
How should I create a label "months" for the rows"counts in the month".

Comment: You have't any month field in database right ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could modify your SQL to...

```
SELECT
  month(`frm_date`),
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `ldpage`
WHERE
  YEAR(`frm_date`) = 2015
GROUP BY
  month(`frm_date`)
```

You also need to have column headings when creating a `DataTable`.

Where you have...
`var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);`

Try...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
  cols: [
    {
      label: 'Month',
      type: 'number'
    },
    {
      label: 'Count',
      type: 'number'
    }
  ]
});
data.addRows(jsonData);
```

Comment: I modified the SQL query but still showing the same error.